# How to get intersection of two classes based on property

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, intersection

I have this class

```
public class FlightSegment{
     public string ClassName { get;set;}
}
```

And I want to get `FlightSegments` with common `ClassName`

```
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new List<FlightSegment>() { 
        new FlightSegment{ ClassName = "A"},
        new FlightSegment { ClassName = "B"}
    };      
    var list2 = new List<FlightSegment>() { 
        new FlightSegment{ ClassName = "B"},
        new FlightSegment { ClassName = "C"}
    }; 

    var listOfLists = new List<List<FlightSegment>>() { list1, list2 };     
    var intersection = listOfLists.Aggregate((previousList, nextList) => previousList.Intersect(nextList).ToList());        
    Console.WriteLine(intersection); //Gives me empty result

}
```

I tried something like this:

```
    var intersection = listOfLists.Aggregate((previousList, nextList) =>   
      previousList.Select(e=>e.ClassName).Intersect(nextList.Select(e=>e.ClassName)).ToList());
```

But gives error:

```
Cannot convert expression type System.Collection.Generic.List<string> to return type System.Collection.Generic.List<FlightSegment>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx) method passing a [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare according to `ClassName` property:

```
class FlightComparer : EqualityComparer<FlightSegment>
{
    public override bool Equals(FlightSegment x, FlightSegment y)
    {
        return x.ClassName == y.ClassName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(FlightSegment obj)
    {
        return obj.ClassName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then, make the intersection using this comparer:

```
var list1 = new List<FlightSegment>() { 
    new FlightSegment{ ClassName = "A"},
    new FlightSegment { ClassName = "B"}
};      
var list2 = new List<FlightSegment>() { 
    new FlightSegment{ ClassName = "B"},
    new FlightSegment { ClassName = "C"}
}; 
var result = list1.Intersect(list2, new FlightComparer());
```

This returns a collection containing only one element `FlightSegment { ClassName = "B" }`.

Using this idea and [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx), you can get the intersection of a group of lists based on a property:

```
var intersection = listOfLists.Aggregate((previousList, nextList) => previousList.Intersect(nextList, new FlightComparer() ).ToList());
```

Comment: Nice answer. Note the guidance in the documentation, "We recommend that you derive from the `EqualityComparer<T>` class instead of implementing the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface  because the `EqualityComparer<T>` class tests for equality using the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method instead of the `Object.Equals` method. "

Comment: Good to know about  inheriting EqualityComparer<T> over implementing IEqualityComparer<T>.